# Unknown column in field list during join

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a customized forum system right now. I've following a couple of tutorials on how to get the categories and subcatagories to be sorted properly on my website. But i'm running into some issues with this query

```
    SELECT
    thread_catagories.`catID`    tc_id
FROM
    thread_catagories tc       
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    thread_catagories   tcP
    ON tc.tc_id = tcP.parent
```

I keep getting a "Unknown Column" error, saying that the catID column doesn't exist, despite being shown when I knock off the Left Outer Join part of the code.

Comment: Once you define an alias you have to use it. The real table name is not valid any more then.

Answer (score 0):

you are joining one table with two aliaces and you dont specify the aliace which you will use in your column.

try that

```
   SELECT
tc.`catID`    tc_id
^^---use which aliace here
FROM
thread_catagories tc       
LEFT OUTER JOIN
thread_catagories   tcP
ON tc.tc_id = tcP.parent
```

im little suspect of this column `tc_id`  or aliace